# mysql database dump. I want to copy production data to my development server. Is this safe to do as production site is up?

Tags: mysql

I want to run this command during the time in which the production server is running the application:

```
mysqldump -u sbp -p databasename_production > databasename_development_copy.sql
```

Is this safe to do while production is running or no?

In short, development would be a lot easier if I had a copy of production data. Is this safe to do?

I'm doing this in digitalocean fwiw.

Comment: [There](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) you can certainly get quality answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be fine, but I would not recommend doing it during core hours or during high traffic/activity on your site/database.

Schedule a job that runs it daily, and then restore your backup file to a development database instance/server. This serves two purposes: 1) You now have a real-ish time database to do dev/troubleshooting against 2) You have confirmed that your daily backups of your database are not corrupted and if something catastrophic happened, you have a functioning backup to restore from.